# File upload not working in expressionengine 2.10.1

Tags: channel-entries, file-uploads, file-manager, ee

I tried uploading a file with a file upload field and with the native File Manager. EE will not respond at all, no pop-up window whatsoever.

All permissions are right and upload destination is ok. Any suggestion what it could be?

Comment: What do you mean by "not respond"? If a pop-up you expect to show up is not showing up, it is almost certainly a front-end javascript error. Have you checked your developer console??

Comment: Developer Tool in Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.academischezorg.nl/cp/?S=e6c3fd07ffd0894a26c848193fe86f1d&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=filemanager_actions&action=setup&_=1438092856774. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.nfu.nl' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @jrothafer 
When trying to add a file develop tool says: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined

(anonymous function) @ ?S=e6c3fd07ffd0894a26c848193fe86f1d&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=datepicker,resizable,draggabl…:101H. 
event.dispatch @ jquery.js?v=1437721190:17H. 
event.add.a.handle.s @ jquery.js?v=1437721190:16

Comment: What's going on here? You seem to be using two different domains related to one installation. Is MSM installed? You're redirecting academicshezorg.nl to nfu.nl. The result is a crossdomain script denial. What is your Site URL and Control Panel URL set to???

Comment: Site URL: www.domain2.nl, CP URL: domain2.nl accept for the third option (theme folder path: that one is set to the origin site (..)/domain1.nl/(...)

Comment: We use a .httaccess to redirect between the two url. We've added a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but now we get a new error.
Uncaught OK,<!DOCTYPE html>
(...)
(anonymous function) @ ?S=2bfbf157dfa312ac64ac0b2bcd493003&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,so…:235(anonymous function) @ ?S=2bfbf157dfa312ac64ac0b2bcd493003&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,so…:222

Comment: You're always going to run into assets trouble trying to load cross-domain, even if you set that header. Dangerous and bad-practice at a minimum; some addons load scripts via the themes folder var `{theme_folder_url}` and some just load it via `{site_url}/themes_whatevers`. All URL vars should all be set to the base domain. You'll have to explain further as to why you're redirecting between two domains (edit your question).

Comment: I agree that all URL vars should be set to the base domain but my hands are tied at the moment. We now solved the problem by fixing the .htaccess file. Thank you for all your input!